# Safely removing eSATA disks

Tags: 12.04, disk, sata, eject

Is there any way to safely remove any external disk connected via eSATA?
Disks make an ugly noise when unplugged, even if there are no mounted partitions
I found this little command somewhere, and it seems to shutdown the disk.

```
sdparm --flexible --command=stop /dev/sdb &>/dev/null
```

But, just when it powers off, it starts working again.

Any clue?

Comment: The problem is present also on USB disks as well. My "solution" is timing. Click "Eject" and the moment I hear the drive spinning down, I detach the cable. Not a nice solution, but there's no ugly noise like that.

Comment: I try doing that using this command.. I think "Eject" does the same.. But I can't find it anywhere (that's a Nautilus context-menu option, right?)

Comment: Actually there used to be an "Eject" option. Now there's only "Unmount". Actually "Eject" was intended for media that can be ejected (CD/DVD). Unmount saves any data which is waiting to be written but does not power off the device, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `echo 1 > /sys/block/<disk>/device/delete`. You'll need to be root to do this.

On my system, this powers off the eSATA disk and deallocates its block device. The disk stays powered off and I can disconnect it at my leisure.

Note: make sure you have unmounted any filesystems first to prevent data loss!

Comment: Thanks. This works great except the disk then won't be reattached until reboot. Is there a quicker way to replug after writing 1 to the delete file?

Comment: Figured it out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/561896/esata-hotplugged-drive-not-recognized : sudo rescan-scsi-bus

Answer (score 1):

There is a procedure when you want to remove SATA disks.

First umount any partitions, and then flush the I/O buffer by entering

```
blockdev --flushbufs /dev/sd?
```

then remove the drive by entering

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sd?/device/delete
```

I guess it can work for eSATA as well.

A question still remains in my mind: are the heads are safely parked in the landing zone with this procedure?

Comment: Correct, this does indeed work for eSATA.