# eSata "HotPlugged" Drive Not Recognized

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, hotplug

So, I have an Optiplex 780 with esata on the back. Under windows, I'm able to hotplug any ol' hard drive using my [Thermaltake eSata USB Docking Station](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001A4HAFS). As soon as I plug in the eSata cable, it spins up the drive and is recognized. Unfortunately, under Ubuntu it doesn't spin up at all.

Under Ubuntu 14.04 I've added `lsscsi`, but I only end up with the following output:

```
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      hp ssd v300a     502A  /dev/sda
[1:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  TSSTcorp DVD+-RW TS-L633C DW50  /dev/sr0
```

(Basically, my system drive and the DVD writer)

The drive does not spin up, and nothing is recognized.

I've tried rescanning using

```
 echo "- - -" | sudo tee -a /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan
```

(for each of the host0-3), But that doesn't seem to improve the situation.

`gparted` also does not show the drive.

In my research I've come across the following:

1. http://bitprison.net/monoig_model_attibutes_translation
2. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

But to no avail. Any ideas?

`lspci` gives the following:

```
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) 4-port SATA IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) 2-port SATA IDE Controller (rev 02)
```

I don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: We need to see your dmesg logs at the time of the hotplug event to diagnose this. Are you even getting a phy event? Is the drive going online and then being pushed offline? Does lspci -k show a driver loaded for that 2-port SATA IDE controller? It could be anything.

Comment: Ah, that's what I needed, I had no idea where to look, I'll report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Did the trick for me:

```
sudo rescan-scsi-bus
```

`rescan-scsi-bus` is in the package `scsitools`, not installed by default, so maybe you will have to install it first:

```
sudo apt install scsitools
```

Comment: Worked for me too (thanks). 14.04 recognized the drive when hotplugged, 16.04 doesn't, but it did with this command.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/732504/429618) provided by prototyp just worked for me using Ubuntu 20.04.

However I found that I needed to do more than eject using Nautilus (or umount from command line) to stop and deregister the disk properly before unplugging.

Summarising:
To detect the disk (credit to prototyp):

```sh
sudo rescan-scsi-bus
```

To list the disks:

```sh
lsscsi
```

Before unplugging the disk (from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/889210/429618)):

```sh
sudo blockdev --flushbufs /dev/<id>
sudo bash -c "echo 1 > /sys/block/<id>/device/delete"
```

where `<id>` is your "block device id" listed for example by `lsscsi`

Failure to do this last step will cause the disk to continue to show after you have unplugged the drive.

Comment: (I could not comment below prototyp's answer as I don't yet have 50 reputation points)